# Ofuscar con php ob_start

Tags: php

Que tal intento ofuscar un código con `php ob_start` y `ob_end_flush` es un formulario, pero no me lo muestra en la pantalla.

`ob_start` en el header,

`php ob_start`('comprimir_pagina'),

El formulario `html`  en el cuerpo,

Y `ob_end_flush` en el pie de la pagina.

```
  // Una vez que el búfer almacena nuestro contenido utilizamos "ob_end_flush" para usarlo y deshabilitar el búfer
  
ob_end_flush();

  // Función para eliminar todos los espacios en blanco

function comprimir_pagina($buffer) {
    $search = array(
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s',     // elimina espacios en blanco después de las etiquetas, excepto el espacio
        '/[^\S ]+\</s',     // elimina en blanco antes de las etiquetas, excepto el espacio
        '/(\s)+/s',         // Acortar múltiples secuencias de espacios en blanco.
        '/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/' // Borrar comentarios html
    );
    $replace = array(
        '>',
        '<',
        '\\1',
       ''
    );

    $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer) 
    return $buffer;
   }
?>
```